# JQuery Sortable - How to avoid content to refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using JQuery sortable list where I dyanmically I can modify the content inside each element (ie, textfield, color, etc). Either I indluce each element content as an iframe of div then this content is refreshed each time I move/drag and drop this element into another position. Which is weird is that it doesn't happend when I move another different element, so my question would be: is there anyway to avoid currentItem to be refreshed/reloaded after draggin it to another position?
Thanks in advance for your help (!)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. See: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5575

Comment: In Atlansian Jira, this bug is resolved, They use iframe in widget of dashboard, while I move widget, iframe not reload. This feature works in all browser. I don't understand how they achieve it.